# Add hyperlink dynamically to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I am generating gridview dynamically. Here is the code

Design Code

```
<asp:GridView Width="100%" CssClass="TTable" ID="MainGridView" OnDataBound = "OnDataBound" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind :

```
private void createGridView(DataTable gridviewdt)
    {
        MainGridView.Columns.Clear();
        //Iterate through the columns of the datatable to set the data bound field dynamically.
        foreach (DataColumn col in gridviewdt.Columns)
        {
            //Declare the bound field and allocate memory for the bound field.
            BoundField bfield = new BoundField();

            //Initalize the DataField value.
            bfield.DataField = col.ColumnName;

            //Initialize the HeaderText field value.
            bfield.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;

            //Add the newly created bound field to the GridView.
            MainGridView.Columns.Add(bfield);

        }

    }

// Bind Datatable to gridview
MainGridView.DataSource = gridviewdt;
MainGridView.DataBind();
```

In the above code, I would like to put hyperlink on particular columns data. If I put the hyperlink directly on the Datatable, then it shows it as it is without executing.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

How can I add above link button on some gridview columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to add a `LinkButton` declaratively in gridview control then we wrap it inside the `TemplateField` and not inside a `BoundField`. Also I am not sure why you are looping through the DataTable (which I guess is the source of the gridview). Correct way to do is by adding the `TemplateField` to columns collection before binding the data to gridview and finally add the control in `RowDataBound` event which is raised for each row which is bound to the gridview.

You can use this:-

In `Page_Load` :-

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   TemplateField myTemplate = new TemplateField();
   myTemplate.HeaderText = "MyLinkButton";
   MainGridView.Columns.Add(myTemplate);
   BindGrid();
}
```

Here, `BindGrid` is the method which will simply bind the data to your gridview:-

```
private void BindGrid()
{
   MainGridView.DataSource = GetData(); \\Your data source here
   MainGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Finally add the `LinkButton` control in the `RowDataBound` event of gridview like this:-

```
protected void MainGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
       LinkButton myLink = new LinkButton();
       myLink.ID = "LinkButton1";
       myLink.Text = "LinkButton";
       myLink.Click += myLink_Click;
       e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(myLink);
   }
}
```

Please note since I have added just 1 column (in the page load) thus I am using `e.Row.Cells[0]` to get the first column. If you add multiple columns then you will have to change the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am looping the datatable to get Header names in the gridview from the datatable. In the above code, if I use `myLink.Text = "LinkButton";`, then my original data getting from the datatable will be replaced. I want to use gridview with datatable's data.

Comment: Here I got it working. I added `myLink.Text = e.Rows.Cells[3].Text`. Thanks for help

Comment: what is this myLink_Click;?